# JSON Array string getting split at space for every value using jq

Tags: arrays, json, shell, jq

i am trying to read commands from the json file using jq.
Although i am able to read content as per requirement but only issue currently facing is that after getting values from json array each string value is automatically getting split a space which is dividing content of string into n no of values instead of one.

*JSON FILE*

```
{
"baseVersion": "abc",
"patches": [{
    "version": "122",
    "description": "This patch contains fixes blah blah blah ",
    "iBuild": "60",
    "files": [{
        "fullPath": "20.6.I60.jar",
        "nodeTypes": [
            "a",
            "b"
        ],
        "productTypes": ["a", "b"],
        "restart": "true",
        "service_commands": [{
            "node_name": ["a"],
            "command": ["ls","date","demo"]
        },{
            "node_name": ["b"],
            "command": ["singleline command00"]
        }]
    }]
}]}
```

*Code to read content*

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'Exit 1' INT TERM
umask 022


getServiceRestartForNode()
{
  local patchConfFile="/pathto/patch_conf.json"

  local query='.patches[] | .version as $v'
  query+=' | .files[] | .service_commands[] |.command[]'

  local outputCommands=($(jq -cr "$query" "$patchConfFile"))

  local result=${PIPESTATUS[0]}

  if [ "$result" -ne 0 ]
  then
    Display -e "ERROR: Error listing files (error code: '$result')"
    return 1
  else

  echo "${outputCommands[@]}"
    for servicecommand in "${outputCommands[@]}"
      do
        "$servicecommand"
    # if [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]]
    # then
    #   display "0" "command $servicecommand failed."
    # fi
      done
  fi
  return 0
}

if  [[ $1 = "-o" ]]; then
    echo "Option -o turned on"
    getServiceRestartForNode
else
    echo "You did not use option -o"
fi
```

*Current output*

```
Option -o turned on
ls date demo singleline command
a.out  demo.sh  patch_conf.json
Wed Jun  2 16:29:23 IST 2021
demo.sh: line 26: demo: command not found
demo.sh: line 26: singleline : command not found
```

*Expected output*

```
Option -o turned on
ls date demo singleline command00
a.out  demo.sh  patch_conf.json
Wed Jun  2 16:29:23 IST 2021
demo.sh: line 26: demo : command not found
demo.sh: line 26: singleline command00 : command not found
```

The last executed "singleline", But it was supposed to be  "singleline command".

Thank you in advance

Comment: Quote all your shell variables/array expansions

Comment: @Inian done please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace these lines:

```
  local outputCommands=($(jq -cr "$query" "$patchConfFile"))

  local result=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

with these lines:

```
  outputCommands=()
  while IFS='' read -r line || ! result=$line; do outputCommands+=("$line"); done < <(jq -r "$query" "$patchConfFile"; echo -n $?)
```

and you should be good to go.

In the JQ command, I'm ditching the `-c` option so that the results print one per line. Then I'm using BASH's `read` to read in the lines one at a time, populating the array with each line (thereby eliminating the word-splitting on the space in the "singleline command00" command). The `<(jq ...)` bit is called "process substitution", and it allows the script to read the output of a process as if it were a file. And finally, the  `|| ! result=$line` and `; echo -n $?` combine to allow proper error checking within the process substitution.

Using an `echo` in place of actually executing the command, the output looks like this:

```
</tmp> $ ./so3428.sh -o
Option -o turned on
ls date demo singleline command00
CMD <ls>
CMD <date>
CMD <demo>
CMD <singleline command00>
```

If I mangle the name of the file to generate a JQ error, I get:

```
</tmp> $ ./so3428.sh -o
Option -o turned on
jq: error: Could not open file x/tmp/so3428.json: No such file or directory
./so3428.sh: line 18: Display: command not found
```

There's more that could be cleaned up in here, but I'll point you to [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for that.